# How to integrate bootstrap3.0 with LESS in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, less, wordpress-theming

I was able to include Bootstrap 3.0 CSS and javascript files with the help of

> wp-bootstrap-navwalker available at:
>
> https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

There wasn't any problem when I included CSS file through `functions.php`

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', array( ), false, 'all' );
```

I did similar to include LESS file, but it didnt work. Below is the code

```
wp_enqueue_style('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less', array( ), false, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/bootstrap/js/less-1.3.3.min.js', array( ), false, 'all' );
```

So generally speaking, how can we integrate Bootstrap LESS file during wordpress theming? (I am using underscores starter theme)

Answer (score 0):

I put this in my functions.php file:

```
/* * ***********LESS Support******************* */

add_action('init', 'theme_enqueue_styles');

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $template_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

    wp_enqueue_style('style', $template_uri . '/resources/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less', array(), false, 'all');
}


//if using WP-LESS with a theme. This location is based on your code above.
```

In my functions I have it set up like this for the scripts:

```
// enqueue javascript
if( !function_exists( "theme_js" ) ) 
{function theme_js(){


wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', 
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/bootstrap.min.js', 
  array('jquery'), 
  '1.2' );

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
}}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
```

Now the theme you are using is a bit different, it's using this pattern:

```
wp_enqueue_script( '_s-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );
```

It would seem that instead of doing

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/bootstrap/js/less-1.3.3.min.js', array( ), false, 'all' );
```

It should be below:

```
   wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/bootstrap/js/less-1.3.3.min.js', array('jquery'), false, false );
```

Correct array should be the version number (not sure why they put in the date). False is default or auto-generated. jQuery I added to the array because Bootstrap relies on jQuery to work. Instead of "all" which is an incorrect parameter, the option is true or false. True passes into the footer before the end body tag. False puts it in the head.

Lastly you should wire up WP-LESS (specifically this version: https://github.com/bassjobsen/wp-lesscss). It's generally as simple as activating it because it looks for any enqueue of less files in your functions.

I would highly recommend to ease your issues with bootstrap, you use a bootstrap framework like 320press or Roots. That way you're not reinventing the wheel :)